C++ syntax question about accessing members
Why is it wrong to access the fun() function this way?
I get this error:

“C++ Operators -> and ->* Applied to Non-Pointer Types”

I can't understand this error!
class a
{
public:
    class b
    {
        struct c
        {
            void fun() {};
        }; 
        c _c[5];

        c* operator[](int count) {
            return &_c[count];
        }

    };
    b* _b;

    static a* _This;
    a();
};

a::a()
{
    _This->_b[1]->fun();
}


// The resources of this class need to be shared among the UIElementMixer and ui component classes
void CloseBaseDisplay();
class BaseDisplay
{
    friend void CloseBaseDisplay();
protected:
    BaseDisplay() {};
    BaseDisplay(const HWND& mainWndHwnd, PositionManager& position);

    static PositionManager                  _PositionManager;
    static int                              _CardMaxCount;
    static HWND                             _MainWindowHwnd;

    static HANDLE                           _hMutex; 
    static CComPtr<IDCompositionTarget>     _Target;
    static CComPtr<IDCompositionVisual2>    _RootVisual;
    static CComPtr<IDCompositionVisual2>    _SwapChainVisual;
    static CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1>         _SwapChain;
};





class UIElementMixer : virtual protected BaseDisplay
{
    static UIElementMixer* _This;
private:
    HANDLE _UIThread;

    bool _IsRun;  // For closing the animation loop
    bool _IsShow; // Control to pause the animation update loop when the window is not displayed


private:
    static HRESULT UpdateAnimation();
    static DWORD WINAPI UIThread(_In_ LPVOID lp);

public:
    UIElementMixer(const int maxCount, const HWND& mainWndHwnd, PositionManager position);
    ~UIElementMixer();
    ERRORID InitializeCard(ID2D1Bitmap* icon[_MAX_MAX_CARD_COUNT], const wchar_t* appPath[_MAX_MAX_CARD_COUNT]); // Create UIElementMixer::_Card

    void StopUpdateAnimation() { _IsShow = false; }
    void StartUpdateAnimation() { _IsShow = true; }

    enum Card_Move_Signal {
        RETURN_TO_ORIGIN,
        MOVE_LEFT_SECONDARY,
        MOVE_LEFT,
        MOVE_RIGHT_SECONDARY,
        MOVE_RIGHT
    };

    enum Card_Scale_Signal {
        SCALE_ORIGINAL,
        SCALE_LEVEL_1,
        SCALE_LEVEL_2,
        SCALE_LEVEL_MAX
    };

    enum Backgrond_Time_Mode {
        DAY, INGHT
    };

    enum MOVE {
        LEFT, RIGHT
    };

    // Manage all cards through a card class
    class Card : virtual protected BaseDisplay
    {
    public:
        Card(ID2D1Bitmap* icon[_MAX_MAX_CARD_COUNT], const wchar_t* appPath[_MAX_MAX_CARD_COUNT]);


    private:
        struct Resource
        {
            friend HRESULT UIElementMixer::UpdateAnimation();
            friend DWORD WINAPI  UIElementMixer::UIElementMixer::UIThread(_In_ LPVOID lp);
            friend class Card;

        public:
            bool IsOk();

            void SelectCard();
            void AddCard(ID2D1Bitmap* icon, const wchar_t* appPath); // 卡片将添加到这个卡片后面
            void DeleteCard();
            void SetTimeMode(Backgrond_Time_Mode mode);

            void MoveCard(MOVE mode);
            void ScaleCard(Card_Scale_Signal mode);


        private:
            const wchar_t* _AppPath;
            CComPtr<ID2D1Effect> _IconScaleManagement;

            Card_Move_Signal _MoveSignal;
            Card_Scale_Signal _ScaleSignal;

            struct Animation {
                FLOAT Scale_Start_Value;
                FLOAT Scale_Cureent_Value;
                FLOAT Scale_Target_Value;

                FLOAT Move_Start_Value;
                FLOAT Move_Cureent_Value;
                FLOAT Move_Target_Value;

                std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> StartTime;
            }; Animation _Animation;
        }; Resource _Resource[_MAX_MAX_CARD_COUNT];


    public:
        Resource* operator[](const int count) {
            if (count < _CardMaxCount) {
                return &_Resource[count];
            }
        }

    }; Card* _Card;
};


Where did you learn C++? The list of things wrong with the code is multiple times longer than the code itself.

@SebastianRedl I think we can assume that this is a [mre]. The code is not intended to be run, just to illustrate the syntactic error.

@SebastianRedl: Removing all those extra pointers would even allows the OP's code to be correct :)

@SebastianRedl This indeed is the minimal reproducible code. However, after hearing your feedback, I realize there might be some issues with my class design. I would really appreciate your help in reviewing it. I've added the code above for your reference. Thank you in advance!

This can be understood by working out the types involved.
_This has type a*, so
_This->_b has type b*, so
_This->_b[i] has type b&. Note that [] is the built-in operator[] not the b::operator[] you defined because _This->b is a pointer. Maybe this is your misunderstanding, b::operator[] only applies to b values not b pointers.
Since _This->b[i] is not a pointer it is illegal to apply built-in operator-> to it.

@Jarod42 Yes, I've added your clarification to my answer.

Thank you for your response, it has been very helpful. However, after reading the comments, I realize my class design issues might be more severe. I will try to revise the design first. If you have the time, could you also help me review the issues in my code design? Thanks again for your help!
